Does IDWriteTextAnalyzer::GetGlyphs() work with ligatures?
I'm trying to turn a string of text into glyph IDs for rendering. I chose the IDWriteTextAnalyzer::GetGlyphs() method, but I can't seem to group even basic ligatures this way. I've tried passing in typographic features in the arguments as well as leaving it null.
For example, "‍‍‍" is shaped as four separate glyph IDs, and "" is shaped as two glyph IDs. These should both be one.
Is GetGlyphs() the correct method to be using? I'm happy with my IDWriteTextAnalyzer solution otherwise, so I'm hoping it's possible to continue to use it. I had trouble getting IDWriteTextRenderer::DrawGlyphRun() to even output the correct glyph IDs normally in my attempts, but I'm willing to revisit it if someone can confirm it works.

Yes, DrawGlyphRun is what you need.  I use it in my renderer.

You should post a reproducing sample to help How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Does it work for you if using the layout object instead, for the same exact text and font? GetGlyphs() is the correct way to get glyph output, and some features will already be enabled by default. I don't know if extra configuration is needed for emoji ranges, but if text layout shapes it, then GetGlyphs() likely produces similar output.

You haven't said anything about what font is being used. That will certainly be relevant for ligature formation: the font needs to support those ligatures.

@MichaelChourdakis I've just switched over my implementation and I can confirm DrawGlyphRun works without hassle!

@bunglehead Good idea, will test it out soon. I heard that IDWriteTextAnalyzer is lower level than IDWriteTextRenderer, so as you said, it should work as well. Maybe I need the correct typographic features set?

@PeterConstable Ah sorry, it turned out that was half of the issue. I was using the built-in Segoe UI Emoji to test, and it seems this font doesn't contain either of those emojis. I'm now using the built-in Cascadia Code to test ligatures, which works with DrawGlyphRun (still testing with GetGlyphs()).

Microsoft does not support flag emoji.
